# Simplify if condition?

Tags: c#, if-statement, refactoring

I have this code:

```
int someValue = 100;
if (x == 5)
{
    if (someCondition)
    {
        return someValue;
    }
    return someValue / 12;
}

if (x == 6)
{
     if (someCondition)
     {
         return someValue * 12;
     }
    return someValue;
}
```

As you see, *someCondition* is always the same, just the returned value differs. Is there a way to simplify this some more?

Comment: Can you give some more *semantic* names to the variables involved? There may well be a way to simplify this which only makes sense when we can understand the purpose of the code.

Comment: only thing I can see is that I would put an else right before if (x == 6)

Comment: I often get exactly the same IFs. Nothing you can do about the verboseness :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's see, what do you think of this?

```
int someValue = 100;

if (x == 5)
 return someCondition ? someValue : (someValue / 12);
else if (x == 6)
 return someCondition ? (someValue * 12) : someValue;
```

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you mean by simplify...

The following has fewer lines of code and doesn't sacrifice anything in terms of readability (IMO):

```
var someValue = 100;
switch (x)
{
  case 5:
    return someCondition ? someValue : someValue / 12;
  case 6:
    return someCondition ? someValue * 12 : someValue;
  default:
    return someValue;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This has no "nested" statements so looks cleaner to me:

```
int someValue = 100;

if ((x == 5 && someCondition) || (x == 6 && !someCondition))
    return someValue;

if (x == 5)
    return someValue / 12;

if (x == 6)
    return someValue * 12;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have different ways to handle the result of the same conditional statement.  Because of this, it is probably more efficient (and easier on the eyes) to keep it the way you have it.

If your `return` expressions were the same for each conditional statement then I would revise the code, but each block of code has a different `return` value and because of that makes it unique.

So no, there really isn't a way to simplify what you've done.

Answer (score 2):

You've got two variables (`x` and `someCondition`), and 3 distinct outcomes; so, yes, you can do better than two pairs of two nested tests. The best you can do is:

```
if (((x == 5) && someCondition)) ||
    ((x == 6) && !someCondition)))
{
  return someValue;
}
else if (x == 5)
{
  return someValue / 12;
}
else if (x == 6)
{
  return someValue * 12;
}
```

Comment: hmm yeah, nicer than mine. +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

A single line of code:

```
condition ? someValue * ((x == 6) ? 12 : 1) : someValue / ((x == 5) ? 12 : 1);
```

**Is this simple?** I think so.
**Is this easy to read?** At some extent.
**Is this good?** I wouldn't say so. (+ the generated IL is slightly different)

Comment: One rule of thumb for readability is to use at most one conditional in a single expression.

Comment: It's a one line command, but I found this is harder to read than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch the `if` statements, so that you only repeat the condition once. You can use a `switch` for checking the `x` value:

```
int someValue = 100;
if (someCondition) {
  switch (x) {
    case 5: return someValue;
    case 6: return someValue * 12;
  }
} else {
  switch (x) {
    case 5: return someValue / 12;
    case 6: return someValue;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Much of a muchness really, how about

```
Double scalar = 12;
switch(x)
{
  case 5 : 
    scalar = 1f/12;
    break;
  case 6 : 
    break;
  default : 
    return 100;
}
if (someCondition)     
{         
  return someValue;     
}     
return someValue * scalar;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
switch(x) {
    case 5: return someCondition ? someValue : someValue / 12;
    case 6: return someCondition ? someValue * 12 : someValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use a switch statement instead of two if statements. Or you could make a function where you pass the x * 12 or x / 12...

Answer (score 0):

Use an object instead of a switch, added "adopting" tests.

```js
const state = {
  5: {
    true: (someValue) => someValue,
    false: (someValue) => someValue / 12
  },
  6: {
    true: (someValue) => someValue * 12,
    false: (someValue) => someValue
  }
}

const test_values = [0, -1 , 1, 12, -12, 1.2, -1.2]

test_values.map(value => Object.keys(state).map(x => Object.keys(state[x]).map(condition => {
  console.log(`value = ${value}, x = ${x}, result = ${state[x][condition](value)}`)
})))
```